# slow resume and sometimes black screen after unlocking screen

Tags: black-screen, bugs

i have elementary 5.1.2 Hera installed and i've been dealing with some really annoying screen freeze.
when i lock the screen (super + L) and then try to log in back the system freezes for like 10-20 seconds, i can move the mouse and if i'm on youtube i can play the video but the screen remains frozen, it's a fresh installation and i don't know why this happens.

any suggestions?

this is my setup:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue on my laptop. So far, I've found this link on the ubuntu forum (since elementary hera is based on Ubuntu 18.04):
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038723/slow-recovering-from-lock-screen-ubuntu-18-04

Also, found those two bugs registered at Ubuntu's Lauchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1832812
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1774188

Running `joarnalctl -b` right after the unlock screen, I get the following log:

```
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[1]: Stopped Session c3 of user lightdm.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd-logind[858]: Removed session c3.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 110...
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Stopped target Default.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Stopping Accessibility services bus...
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service...
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Stopped Accessibility services bus.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Stopped target Basic System.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Stopped target Sockets.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Stopped target Timers.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Stopped target Paths.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Reached target Shutdown.
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Starting Exit the Session...
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[24408]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 25227 (kill).
abr 21 15:57:09 Gnotebook systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 110.
**abr 21 15:57:09** Gnotebook systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of lightdm.
abr 21 15:57:15 Gnotebook kernel: amdgpu: [powerplay] VI should always have 2 performance levels
abr 21 15:57:15 Gnotebook kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: GPU pci config reset
abr 21 15:57:23 Gnotebook gsd-color[2202]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xran
abr 21 15:57:23 Gnotebook gsd-color[2202]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xran
**abr 21 15:57:23** Gnotebook io.elementary.a[7686]: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -5 and height 16
```

Notice the highlighted timestamps: They have 14 seconds of interval, that is roughly the time I spend wating the screen unlock.

For now, my hint is that's something about the error messages from the gsd-color bin:

```
 abr 21 15:57:23 Gnotebook gsd-color[2202]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xran
    abr 21 15:57:23 Gnotebook gsd-color[2202]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xran
```

But no clue how to fix it. Just giving more info to help others.

Below are my laptop settings.

[image]

Comment: did you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Maybe with eOS 6 (ubuntu 20.04 based) they fix this.

Comment: yes, i'm couting on that, but still no release date :/